# Eclipse: Automatically add "use namespace"

Tags: php, eclipse, namespaces, php-5.3, eclipse-pdt

I am refactoring a big PHP project (more than 500 PHP files) into namespace tree structure.

Is there a way to get Eclipse PDT automatically add *use ...* at the top of the file when an undefined class is encountered?

Otherwise: is there a way to get Eclipse PDT highlight undefined classes, so that i can do sort of *right click -> add namespace*, like in Microsoft Visual Studio?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse will not add use statement on save, only while ctrl+space.

You can install Pex-Core plugin. It have class usage validator and quick assist (ctrl + 1) "inject use statement". Available at http://p2.pdt-extensions.org

Comment: This is exaclty what i'm looking for. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

I offer https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/

and read this document

https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PHP+Namespaces+and+PSR+Support+in+PhpStorm#PHPNamespacesandPSRSupportinPhpStorm-DetectingNamespacesnotfollowingthePSR-0orPSR-4Configuration